# Analyzing homogeneity of variances in R with Residuals vs Fitted plot

Tags: r, plot, nested, anova, variance

I am fairly new to R and I have just performed a nested ANOVA on my data. I am trying to plot a residuals versus fitted values plot with this. Below is my code and my plot received. Was this the proper way about doing this and if so, can I assume equal variances of my two sites based on my results?

Code:

```
plot(Q1_data.lme,main="Residuals versus Fitted Values Plot")
```

[image: Picture of residual versus fitted plot]

Comment: You have a linear model with a factor (2 levels) as predictor .. So this diagnostic plot might not be the best... Or at least I cannot tell from this plot whether the variances are similar. You can try bartlett.test ..

Comment: Stat methods, theory, and interpretations questions belong on CrossValidated.com

Answer (score 0):

First fit a model and then use the following code to plot the residuals,

```
ols_plot_resid_fit(your_model)
```